# Receiving sql injection attack while trying to store a text with sql statements

Tags: c#, sql

I have a column in database table of type text. This column can contain sql statements.
When I try to insert this text into sql server I am getting a sql injection attack from anti virus software instaleld on teh machine.

How do i escape the text so that anti virus does not catch it.

One sample text is :

```
"*By supplying a malformed @scriptfile parameter an attacker can run arbitrary
commands:
use master
declare @cmd nvarchar(4000)
exec sp_MScopyscriptfile N'c:\autoexec.bat" c:\cp.txt&amp;echo hello &gt;
c:\ccc.bbb &amp; echo "hello',@cmd OUTPUT
print @cmd
The above query will copy the autoexec.bat file to cp.txt but also echo hello to a file called ccc.bbb.* "
```

Comment: What is you code to insert it now?

Answer (score 0):

I would try encoding the text somehow before you store it in the database.  Something as simple as Rot13 should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use Parameters.

All of the main RDBMS have them available in C#.

Comment: I'm thinking he is using parameters, but something running on the SQL server is preventing it anyway (although I might be reading between the lines a bit too much here)

Comment: I am using sqlbulkcopy to insert a datatable. The string is a legitimate string which contains sql statements, the anti virus however thinks i am doing a sql injection attack.